# Raspberry pi and Pusher

Tags: python, html, linux, raspberry-pi, pusher

I currently have a DS18B20 temperature sensor hooked up to my raspberry pi, which data I can read using this piece of code:

```
import time

def main():
    while True:
        tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000051e739/w1_slave")
        text = tfile.read()
        tfile.close()
        secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
        temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
        temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
        temperature = temperature / 1000
        print "Temperature: ", temperature, "C"
        time.sleep(0.5)
main()
```

This works just fine in the terminal.
I also have apache2 installed and working on my raspberry pi.
Now I am trying to display the data that I get from the temperature sensor onto my webpage in **real time**. I followed some tutorials on getting python scripts working in html(http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/writing-cgi-scripts-in-python.html), but it is not in real time. Therefore I googled and found Pusher. An hour of googling later, I couldn't find anything similar to my project.

Can anyone help me?

(I'm sorry for any English mistakes, English isn't my native language)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the loop and run the CGI from Apache?  Every time someone loads the page it will show the current temperature.  You could have a little helper script that does `sudo yourcode.py` and then add `yourcode.py` to the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: Because I don't want to refresh the webpage everytime I want to get a new reading.